# using redux-persist-transform-encrypt with redux-toolkit in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

> after updating the code below,now this the way to use edux-persist-transform-encrypt with redux-toolkit and redux-persist to encrypt data that you saved in storage.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./cart";
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore, FLUSH,
        REHYDRATE,
        PAUSE,
        PERSIST,
         PURGE,
       REGISTER, } from 'redux-persist';
import { encryptTransform } from "redux-persist-transform- 
encrypt";

const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   storage,
   transforms: [ encryptTransform({
       secretKey: "123456",
       onError: (err) => {
       console.log("err", err);
      }
    })]
    }

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, 
  cartReducer)

  export const store = configureStore({
         reducer: persistedReducer,
         middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
                 getDefaultMiddleware({
                      serializableCheck: {
                        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, 
                                       PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
                       },
                     }),
                   })

    export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Comment: This is not a question?

Comment: i need a help to use this package redux-persist-transform-encrypt to encrypt data that has stored in storage.

Comment: i tried to use the package but the cartReducer returns undefiend!!